# How to ask the user for a precise time including timezone on DialogFlow?

Tags: node.js, date, entity, dialogflow-es, jovo-framework

I've created an `Intent` on DialogFlow that expects a user to supply an entity for time, using responses such as:

- *"I'm looking to arrange for about **Eight O'Clock**"*
- *"**Quarter past nine** tonight."*
- *"I'm thinking around **ten past five**."*

DialogFlow has been very smart in correctly identifying the relevant entities in each invocation as `sys.time`.

My application, however, deals with a number of different timezones. So when these values for time actually reach my webhook, I lose the ability to reliably compare the information they're providing against different timezones. i.e. I receive values like `08:50`.

As a workaround, I know I could use the [Google Maps Time Zone API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/timezone-backend.googleapis.com/?q=time) in conjunction with a user's `location`, but I'd like my application to work without requiring special location permissions.

So, I'm wondering, is it possible to configure my `Intent` to recognize these raw time values as `sys.datetime`? I don't want to burden the user with having to specify the date, if possible, and make assumptions that they just mean "today" if they provide just a time value. Is it possible to do this natively within DialogFlow, or is it more likely that I'll need to write a handler on my webhook?

Comment: This post has some relevant date related to Alexa. I believe this will give you some reference, https://medium.com/@cpenarrieta/one-way-to-get-the-user-current-time-from-your-alexa-skill-88b6d2b1aecf